# Error de sintaxis en python, pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Estoy intentando exportar un dataframe en Jupyter Notebook a una planilla excel con la siguiente línea de código :

```
df.to_excel('data.xlsx', sheet_name='países')

print('Listo')
```

Estoy siguiendo la clase de un curso, donde el profesor puede correr bien la misma línea y yo no. Previamente corre todo el código por lo tanto el nombre del df estaría bien, según la documentación no reconoce el módulo de .to_excel()

Comment: Cual es tu dataframe??

Comment: El df es un fichero de datos con diccionarios, no sé como adjuntarlo soy nueva en esto :D debería funcionar puesto que en la clase vengo siguiendo el mismo código y hasta la anterior línea corría, ya luego jupyter notebook no reconoce el módulo. Mi duda es si la sintaxis es la correcta, entonces debo tener un problema previo yo.

Comment: Haz un `print(type(df))` si vez que el resultado es algo como `pandas.DataFrame` tu variable `df` es correcta. Revisa una línea anterior a la que genera el error y verifica que hayas cerrado todas las comillas, corchetes o paréntesis que tengas

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, intentaré con eso!!! Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

Como dice la [documentación](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/install.html), para que los métodos `to_excel` and `read_excel` funcionen, tienes que instalar uno o más de los siguientes módulos en conjunto con pandas:

```
Dependency    Minimum Version    Notes
xlrd          2.0.1              Reading Excel
xlwt          1.3.0              Writing Excel
xlsxwriter    1.2.2              Writing Excel
openpyxl      3.0.3              Reading / writing for xlsx files
pyxlsb        1.0.6              Reading for xlsb files
```

Si instalas por ejemplo `openpyxl`, podrás leer y escribir archivos de Excel